# Share raw resource via WhatsApp (No SDcard)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i trying to share a mp3 audio from the app, the problem is, the audio sends without format, i read about saving it to the external memory and then share it, but i dont have a external memory, there is a way like saving it to internal memory or something like that? thanks. here is the code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("audio/mpeg3");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Los simuladores");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://arg.com.cevascoit.botoneralossimuladores/" + R.raw.teagachas));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getString(R.string.app_name)));

            return false;
```

Comment: "but i dont have a external memory" -- nearly every Android device has [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html). "(No SDcard)" -- an SD card is not what the Android SDK refers to as external storage.

Comment: Oh sorry, im new in this. then, why when i use the code for save in external storage i have an error?

Comment: You may want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve]. This would include the details of the error (such as a stack trace) and your code that is triggering the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a FileProvider like in this example:

First create a file in internal storage (eg.your mp3 file)

```
File sharedDir = new File(getFilesDir(), "shared");
if (!sharedDir.exists())
   sharedDir.mkdir();

File fileToShare = new File(sharedDir, "hello_world.txt");

Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileToShare));
writer.write("Hello World");
writer.close();
```

Then define the FileProvider in the manifest

```
<provider
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="ese.fileprovider"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true"
  android:exported="false">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />;
</provider>;
```

Then specify the directories to be shared in a filepaths.xml

```
<files-path
      name="shared files"
      path="shared/" />
```

Create an URI for the file

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "ese.fileprovider", fileToShare);
```

Share the file

```
Intent shareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

shareFile.setType("application/pdf");
shareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sharing " + fileToShare.getName());
shareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sharing File");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareFile, "Share File"));
```